# SQL wildcard behaving differently in interactive SQL than SQLRPGLE

Tags: wildcard, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have SQL statement that works properly using STRSQL interactively.  There is a wildcard statement: **(MSSHIP NOT LIKE 'T%')** that works properly.  When I copy the statement to a SQLRPGLE program receive the message "Token T is not valid". Of course I used ''T'' defining the statement in the SQL string, however in debug the statement translates properly (pasted from the debugger: **601   'NOT LIKE 'T%') AND**

I've checked the syntax of the entire statement and everything appears fine.  I can remove the LIKE statement and it works.  Is there any reason wildcards can't be used SQLRPGLE?

Comment: show your actual code...also relevant variable declarations...

Comment: but the short answer is yes, you can use SQL wildcards in embedded SQL...you're doing something wrong.

Comment: without your code, your question is of poor quality.  See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Add your code, I'll remove the downvote.  In addition someone will be able to tell you what you've done wrong.

Comment: I didn't reveal code because it's is corporate data and didn't want to show file names.  I even doctored the field name for my simple question.  Asked asked and answered. Thank you.

Comment: If you really think a 6-10 character table or column name are top secret, then by all means change them before posting.  The point of SO isn't 1 word answers.  The point of SO is good questions and answers to help the next person.

Comment: Charles is right, add your code. Change the names to protect the innocent, if you truly think it matters for security. But frankly, if someone could exploit the names, they're probably able to discover the names anyway. We're not asking for the whole program, just the relevant snippet(s) & definitions.